# Cannot start SQL server Agent on windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2019-express

I'm trying to start SQL server Agent on windows 10, I'm getting following error.  - SQL server Agent have installed with SQL express - custom installation
[image]

Following things which I tried to resolve this issue with no luck. :(

1. Change Built in account to Local system - didn't work.
2. Tried to use Network service account didn't work.
3. I have uninstalled the SQL server stand alone and reinstalled it. - Didn't work.
4. Tried to run the services from Services.msc - didn't work

I see SQL server and SQL server browser services running without any issues. But I cannot start sql server agent.

Comment: Did you look in the event log, like the error message told you to? If so, what did it say?

Comment: Agent is not supported on Express. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMS).

Comment: I've voted to close this as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" as the underlying fact is that the OP didn't check the documentation on what features are (or more specifically aren't) supported by the edition of SQL Server they are using. They will either need to use the development version, if this is for **non-production** work, or if it is a production environment they will need to purchase licences for a standard version of SQL Server. Otherwise they will need to use a different scheduling tool; which is a completely different question and not really on topic for [so].

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL Agent doesn't come with SQLExpress. Been that say what say on the event logs of windows? Can you post that information here?

How do you manage to install the agent?

I suggest if you are using SQL Express, you use some other tool to simulate the agent (I have done this with Jenkins, Ansible and Task Scheduler with some PowerShell/batch scripts)

Comment: It could also just be disabled. Try this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/enable-sql-server-agent-service-by-t-sql-script-or-powershell

Comment: I don't think is disable because if that were the case I will not allow trying to start in the first place